# Post JSON data via API and create a related model in Django Rest Framework

Tags: json, django, post, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am performing an API project with the Django Rest Framework.

I have a Django model defined in the following way:

```
class Profile(CreatedUpdatedModel, models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Owner, models.CASCADE)
    start_date = models.DateField(gettext_lazy("Start"), help_text=gettext_lazy("YYYY-MM-DD format"))
    end_date = models.DateField(gettext_lazy("End"), help_text=gettext_lazy("YYYY-MM-DD format"))
    category = models.ManyToManyField(OwnerCategory)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(OwnerTag)
```

I perform a POST API call from the web page that pass a JSON data like the following :

```
{start_date: '2019-11-20' , end_date: '2019-11-21', owner: '65', category: '[20, 21, 22]', tags: '[]' }
```

I would like to save on the database the model with the parameter I passed with JSON

Here is my REST view in views.py:

```
@permission_required()
class ProfileViewSet(ViewSet):

    @action(detail=False, methods=['post'])
    def new_profile(self, request, pk=None):
        serializer = serializers.ProfileSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

and here it is my REST serializer in serializers.py

```
class ProfileSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('owner', 'start_date', 'end_date', 'category', 'tags', )
```

The problem is that the statement `serializer.is_valid()` is `False`.
Where I am wrong with this code ?

Can someone help me ?

-----**EDIT** ----

I looked at `serializer.errors` and this is the output:

```
{'owner': [ErrorDetail(string='This field is required.', code='required')], 'category': [ErrorDetail(string='Expected a list of items but got type "str".', code='not_a_list')], 'tags': [ErrorDetail(string='This field is required.', code='required')]}
```

I also looked at `request.data` I see that the dictionary contains all the data I passed via API

Comment: You should look at `serializer.errors`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I edited my answer reporting the ```serializer.errors``` output.

Comment: Is this still unclear for you? You are sending the bad data, nothing wrong with your code.

Answer (score 0):

What you are sending is not valid json data. Here is how what you have would look in json:

```
{
    "start_date": "2019-11-20",
    "end_date": "2019-11-21",
    "owner": 65,
    "category": [
        20,
        21,
        22
    ],
    "tags": []
}
```